# Download counter: cgi FieldStorage reset pressed button values

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm integrating a download counter for my website. My aim is to trigger the counter each time the Download button is clicked and file downloaded.
The Download button is here:

```
<form action="download.py" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Download" name="DL" onClick="download_file()"/>
</form>
```

When clicked, a file is downloaded, however, I want to trigger the download counter too:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
def count():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO dl VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (index, dt, ip, client))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if "DL" in form:
    count()
    form.list = []
```

In theory, this seems to work, however, the cgi.FieldStorage doesn't get reset if the page is re-loaded, and with each re-load it triggers the DB with a new download, which didn't happen.

How could I completely reset or delete the value stored by the FieldStorage? Or is there a better solution you may advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave a solution for googlers. I sorted the issue by checking what was the last IP address of person downloading the file. If the IP is same as person downloading again (repeated download, or a page refresh), then the counter isn't triggered. The code for it is below:

Get current IP:

```
ip = (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") or
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") or
getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") or
"UNKNOWN")
```

Get last IP that downloaded the file:

```
last_ip_raw = c.execute('SELECT ip FROM dl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
last_ip_tup = c.fetchone()
last_ip = str("%s" % last_ip_tup)
```

Check if downloaded already:

```
def count():
        if last_ip != ip:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO dl VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (index, dt, ip, client))
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
```

I know it's not perfect, but it does the job. Any better suggestions would be welcome.